# Calling Class level code inside block crashes objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

I have a function which calls a get service and returns data to a block which is passed as argument to the function. 
I have had created a generic block function handler that can take any block as argument which has two variables as parameters. One being `BOOL` and other being id.

Issue is that if I add any line that contains code containing class level functions/attributes in 'calling function' then code crashes at dispatch in 'called function'

## Calling function

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    Controller * __weak controller = self;

    [network getWithBlock:(__bridge void *)(^(BOOL isSuccess, id responseData)
     {
         if(isSuccess)
         {
             NSLog(@"Successful Get");
             NSDictionary *data = responseData;
             if(data == nil)
             {
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"It is working %@");
                 [self emptyFunction];  // [controller emptyFunction];                 
             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Failure");
         }
     })];
}
```

## Called function

```
- (void) getWithBlock:(void *) block
{
    //some code
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
       {
           NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
           void (^responseBlock)(BOOL isSuccess,id object) = (__bridge_transfer typeof(responseBlock)) block;
//some response conversion into dict

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               responseBlock(YES, dict);
           });
     }];

    [postDataTask resume];
```

}

## Problem

Issue is if I comment the line `[self emptyFunction]` block is executed and there is no crash. But If I uncomment that line or add any other line that contains controller's variable/class level variables (Calling controller) then crash occurs at Called function at dispatch line.

I have tried various ways. Called it in `viewDidAppear`. Made weak reference to controller and then called the function but no use.

I am unable to understand why class level variables if being called in block is causing me error.

Comment: what kind of error? When is that block called? Is the object already deallocated? Why are you doing the block conversion inside the getWithBlock method? Why not be typesafe and accept only one kind of block? Try printing `controller` after `it is working` to see wether it is nil or pointing to the correct object.

Comment: Error is simply EXE BAD. No details on console. Simple crash occurs. Whenever I execute that code in viewWillAppear code crashes without any log.

Comment: Block is called in viewWillAppear.

Comment: I am doing conversion because I am expecting that second argument is a block which can have two arguments and any type of block can be passed as argument to the function

Comment: I checked self. It is invalid expression in that block in case of success. Block does somehow not know what is self. It is a bad expression for it. Therefore no variable at all is being recognized.

Comment: Does it crash when you use `self` or when you use `controller`?

Comment: If you expect only a block which accepts two parameters then you should make that clear in the method signature, then you would not need any conversion, would be typesafe, etc.

Comment: Yes that is correct, If I specify block in without casting etc.then that works fine. But I am unable to track the issue inside the shared function.

Comment: Yes it crashes with self.

Comment: Okay, lets ignore the block-type-thingy for now

Comment: probably because self is not correct in this context, self refers to the network object, not the controller object. where is that `empty` function defined? I currently don't really understand your problem: does using `controller` fix your problem and you basically want to know why using self does not work?

Comment: You have to provide a stack trace, and the exception.  It's there, so learn how to find it.

Comment: Called function is defined in another Network.m class. I have a object named 'network = [[Network alloc] init]' in the Controller named X. ViewWillAppear and empty function is defined in Controller named X.

Comment: @I00phole there is no stack trace, that's why I myself is unable to track the issue.

Comment: @luk2302 yes, i am unable to understand why self and its variables are not recognized which is the reason for crash.

Comment: `self` in the context of the block passed inside the `network getWithBlock:` call refers to the `network` object and not the calling object, the controller. I cannot really explain it any better, you should probably read about it in more depth in the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

Comment: @luk2302, I understand what you are saying. But if remove (__bridge void *) while calling genWithBlock and line (__bridge_transfer typeof(responseBlock)) block inside genWithBlock, I get self perfectly successful. I believe deferencing into __bridge_transfer somehow removes the self of controllerX.

Answer (score 0):

Using `__bridge_transfer` there is wrong. `__bridge_transfer` consumes a retain count. However, you have never done an unbalanced retain of that block object. So this will likely cause an over-release. You should change it to just `__bridge` instead.

Furthermore, you should move the cast from `void *` (non-managed pointer type) back to block type to the outside of the block sent to `dataTaskWithRequest:`, because the block needs to know that it's capturing a variable of block type, in order to copy it correctly when it itself is copied.